# Insert Data to Database - LINQ

Tags: c#, database, linq

There is some data in my `datagridview`. I want to insert all that data at once into database from `datagridview` using LINQ. But, it couldn't be inserted.

Here is my code :

```
DetailTransaction dt = new DetailTransaction();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dt.TransactionID = labelID.Text;
    dt.ProductID = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    dt.Quantity = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
}

dc.DetailTransactions.InsertOnSubmit(dt);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Can anyone tell me what is the correct code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate a collection of `DetailTransaction` and then use [`InsertAllOnSubmit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable.insertallonsubmit(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
List<DetailTransaction > list = new List<DetailTransaction>();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DetailTransaction dt = new DetailTransaction();
    dt.TransactionID = labelID.Text;
    dt.ProductID = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    dt.Quantity = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
    list.Add(dt);
}
dc.DetailTransactions.InsertAllOnSubmit(list);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

With your current code, you will end up with a single row inserted in the database and that row will be holding the records of the last row in `dataGridView1`

Comment: I have tried that code. But there is some error message : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This message is on dt.ProductID = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
Where is the error located? In datagriedview? Thx

Comment: @KemikoSetiawan, that means that there is a null value in `Cell[0]` or some row, explicitly check it and then call `ToString` on it